# "standard" Java DateBuilder implementation?

Tags: java, date

I'd like to know if there is a "standard" Java implementation of a DateBuilder before I build one myself.  I have looked in the java API and Apache Commons and can't seem to find reference to one.

I am looking for something simple that would implement an interface like:

```
Date date = new DateBuilder().month(2).year(1).build();
```

where `date` would be July 12, 2010 (assuming today is May 12).

Also, please no references to Joda Time.

Comment: *lol* @ no references to Joda Time, nicely played. (Would have been my first answer, too.) I haven't seen any DateBuilders myself, but I figured I shouldn't post a non-answer, so I'm commenting a non-answer instead. :-P

Comment: Does it still count if the Joda Time reference is in the question? I think it does.

Comment: @mmyers: Not sure I understand your comment correctly...if the OP wants to have no Joda Time, there isn't really a way to request this except by referring to Joda Time. So the "please no references to Joda Time" doesn't apply to the question itself. :-P

Comment: "Also, please no references to Joda Time." ---> why not?

Comment: @dfa: Because, as far as I know, it does not have a compatible API to the original Date/Calendar classes, meaning that if you had interfaces that used the latter, you'd have to change all of those too. That's not feasible in a mature project. I'd love to be corrected, though.

Comment: Because my need for date manipulation is no more than a simple builder will provide and I don't want to add another library for what in practice be a simple wrapping (a la matt b's answer).  I had just (apparently wrongly) assumed this simple functionality would already exist.

Comment: you can build your Date with jodatime.. then just call toDate()

Comment: no, there is no stardard class... Java stardard date class are broken. Jodatime is a tiny library widely tested, it is not an EJB container :)

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: I mean "count" for the purposes of "every Java date/time question must have a reference to Joda Time". I see there's a deleted answer mentioning it also, so between them, that ought to count. *checks off square on SO Bingo*

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can accomplish the same (just not in a single line / chained method calls) with the Calendar object:

```
//assuming your use case is "add 1 year and 2 months to the current date/time"
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.clear();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

It should be trivial to wrap `Calendar.add()` and `Calendar.set()` yourself in the Builder pattern.

Comment: I presume that's exactly what the OP was planning to do, if there are no standard libraries that provide equivalent functionality. (In other words, this is a non-answer, IMO.)

Comment: Yeah well I felt like "Nope" was too short :)

Answer (score 0):

Google codesearch turns up [this](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#g7Y8u8uY_lw/trunk/common/java/org.jitterbit.util/src/org/jitterbit/util/time/DateBuilder.java&q=datebuilder)

Any use?

Comment: Jitterbit isn't exactly a standard library, is it? Nice try though.

Comment: Agreed, but then the answer is "no", I think. But at least now the OP has a way of getting an implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for [JSR-310](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/). That will be the standard in the future when it is implemented!